# using F2Py through Python code

Tags: python, fortran, portable-executable, f2py

How to use `F2Py` through Python instead of calling it in command line?

I have a [portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/) in use, am not able to install Python. Thus it is not possible to install packages except those work if I unzip the package and copy all to the folder 'site-packages'. Having these mentioned, it is also impossible to change environmental variables, i.e., `path` (cannot be changed, appended;) though it is not possible to call commands 'F2Py' in short form.
Although `F2Py` is part of numpy and numpy is installed in the portable Python, there is no 'F2Py.py' installed anywhere.
The question is how to use `F2Py` to compile Fortran code being used in Python considering the access limtation etc?
*Note that there is a `GFortran` binary unpacked in a folder.*

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't really understand your explanation, from the first sentence it would seem that what you want to do is to get the equivalent of `f2py -c -m hello hello.f` in python:

```
from numpy import f2py
f2py.compile(open('hello.f').read(), 'hello')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does work if you have installed Python and GFortran, however for my case both are just unpacked. There is no registry info associated with them. Thus the code provided didn't work for me.